# How to create new type in sqllachemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, alembic

Hi I want to create new field in **sqlalchemy** similar to **FileField** from Django

```
from sqlalchemy import String

class FileField(String):
"""A mixin that adds field for storing files"""

def __init__(self, length=None, filename='test'):
    super().__init__(length=length)
    self.filename = filename

def some_method(self):
    pass
```

Then in different file, I have imported FileField, and looks like this:

```
class NewModel():
"""A user of the app."""
__tablename__ = 'new_model'

logo = Column(FileField(30), unique=True, nullable=False)

def __init__(self, name: str, symbol: str, logo: FileField, **kwargs):
    db.Model.__init__(
        self,
        logo=logo,
        **kwargs,
    )
```

migration looks like:

```
def upgrade():
    op.create_table('new_table',
    sa.Column('logo', coin_portal.database.FileField(length=30), nullable=False),
```

But ! :(
when using:

- **FileField is string** and has no .filename property
- Methods are not visible

So my question is how to create a new field which is not just string?

Comment: why are you trying to add a filename attribute to your custom type? from a database perspective this makes no sense. it sounds like maybe filename should be a separate column with the String type?

Comment: Need to store URL of an image - it would be **VARCHAR** anyway, But just want to have dedicated field type like **FileField** from Django. Besides on this custom field I will have other methods as well